# What free software are you using for bookkeeping? Why?

Tags: invoices, estimation, time-tracking, accounting

As a freelancer, FreshBooks has traditionally been the 800-pound gorilla but waht other programs are people using the track jobs and revenue (assuming that you are small enough still that you aren't using something like QuickBooks.)

I have been working on a [free FreshBooks alternative](https://zipbooks.com/free-freshbooks-alternative/) and I want to make sure I am covering all my bases in terms of the features that people need to have. For example, Wave is free but doesn't have autobilling. FreshBooks has a great autobilling feature but doesn't do time tracking, etc. Seems pretty fragmented to me and would be interesting in putting all the features in one place.

Here are the software programs I have tried:

Wave Accounting: is very good option as it has double-entry bookkeeping for your more stringent accounting and has payroll integration. It is missing time tracking and autobilling.

FreshBooks: doesn't have time tracking but does do autobilling. They recently removed their free option so I am not sure how to compare them to free options.

NutCache: is free and a good option but no autobilling.

Invoiceto.me : free invoicing but it a one-off deal where you  aren't saving any of the information that you put into the invoice.

I am wondering is autobilling not a necessary feature because consulting is mostly one-off jobs and there isn't a need to process the same charge to the same customer month after month?

Comment: Hi Brad, welcome to Freelancing.SE! This is reading as a list based question, which would be considered too broad for the SE Network. Can you [edit] to ask for a specific problem to be solved? For Software Recommendations (what this boils down to), show a list of what you've tried, why they didn't work, and bullet points of what you require. This will make the question much more answerable and useful to the community. If you have questions on this, please ask in [meta] or on [chat]. Thanks!